# How to install Litecoin

Tags: 12.04, qt

I'm trying to install litecoin on my ubuntu 12.04 machine.

I downloaded the Litecoin-Qt from http://litecoin.org/ and extracted it to `~/`

Then based on the README, I did the following:

> oshirowanen@desktop:~/litecoin/bin/64$ ./litecoin-qt

This `runs` Litecoin, but it does not `install` it, i.e. when I click the super key on the keyboard to bring up the unity navigation and type in `Litecoin`, it is not found as an installed application on my computer.

So my question is, how do I `install` litecoin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to install it to use it. If you are looking for ways to find it easily,

1. add it to the Unity side bar
2. Right click between the Ubuntu icon and the Applications menu at the top panel, select `Edit Menus`. Add `LiteCoin` as one of the entries.

Please see the sample below

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I know this is over 4 years old, however, I am replying so that people who google this issue will come across the answer. OK, so:

```
wget https://download.litecoin.org/litecoin-0.14.2/linux/litecoin-0.14.2-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz
cd ~  # (or your download directory for wget) (~ is your home directory)
tar -xvfz litecoin-0.14.2-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz
sudo install -m 0755 -o root -g root -t /usr/local/bin litecoin-0.14.2/bin/*
litecoind -daemon
Litecoin server starting
litecoin-cli getmininginfo
```

Allow it to sync.

```
litecoin-cli stop
```

Comment: `wget https://download.litecoin.org/litecoin-0.16.3/linux/litecoin-0.16.3-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz`

Comment: I wouldn't install it as sudo.