# Installing litecoin-qt in Ubuntu

Tags: qt

Why can't I run the litecoin-qt file in the bin directory of the archive downloaded from litecoin.org? I copied it into the home directory and double-clicked, and also tried to to run it from terminal. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and the downloaded archive is Litecoin Core 0.15.1. The error message I get is "There is no application installed for 'shared library' files. Do you want to search for an application to open this file?" Clicking Yes produces nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Litecoin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290457/how-to-install-litecoin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me.

First, open a terminal (press Windows key -> gnome-terminal).  Then run the following commands:

```
# Assuming you downloaded the .tar.gz file from litecoin.org
# to ~/Downloads...
cd ~/Downloads
tar -zxf litecoin.*.tar.gz
cd litecoin-0.15.1
bin/litecoin-qt
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly. I'm all synced. It appears right now I can only open the wallet from Terminal, which is fine, but do you know a way to create a desktop icon?

Comment: Hey there, basically this -- https://askubuntu.com/questions/112186/how-do-you-create-a-custom-application-launcher-in-gnome-shell

Comment: Alacarte worked. All set.